# What is the proper usage of "also","too" and "as well"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

When I want to talk to someone and the sentence I am using has "too" or "also" or "as well" in it, I get confused and feel like I am using the wrong structure.

For example:

> Friend: It's raining here
>
> Me: I wish it was raining here **too** ( or *I wish it was also raining here* OR *I wish it was raining here as well*)

or

> Friend: I read books
>
> Me: I read books **too** (*I also read books* OR *I read books as well*)

I would appreciate it if you could tell me the correct structure or suggest an alternative for this

Answer (score 0):

*'Also'* is more common in writing. Said that, in speaking, 'too' and 'as well' are common. So, 'also' in *this way* is *out!*

Between 'too' and 'as well', I think 'too' is used more in response to some wishes or opinions. Say -

> I like french fries ~ Yes, me *<del>as well</del> too*! 
>  Love you! ~ Love you too!

So, to answer this, if it's in response and agreement, 'too' sounds more natural to me.

> I read books ~ Yeah, me too!

And, for 'wish', it's 'as well'

> I wish it was raining here as well.

However, you may find 'too' and 'as well' both in such context but when there's a *pronoun*, and it is a short answer of agreement, 'too' sounds better.