# He works in the shop and she does too / also / as well

Tags: meaning

Are the following have the same meaning?

> He works in the shop and she does **too** / **also** / **as well**. [English Vocabulary in Use](http://www.cambridge.org/us/cambridgeenglish/catalog/grammar-vocabulary-and-pronunciation/english-vocabulary-use-elementary)

If yes, what is the following mean?

> **The only difference is in their placement in the sentence.** Too and as well are used at the end of a sentence. (As well is more formal than too). Also usually goes before the verb or adjective. [Espresso English](https://www.espressoenglish.net/difference-between-also-too-and-as-well/)

and this source consider the following is wrong:

> I like chocolate also.

Note: I don't find the the answer within the following questions:

1. [What is the proper usage of “also”,“too” and “as well”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/68697/what-is-the-proper-usage-of-also-too-and-as-well)
2. [“I have sent it to X too” vs. “I have sent it to X also”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16421/i-have-sent-it-to-x-too-vs-i-have-sent-it-to-x-also)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine to put "also" at the end of a sentence, although it does sound less formal.  All of these have the same meaning:

> I do too
>
> I do also
>
> I do as well

There are English speakers who would object, and say it's not *proper*, but there is a wide variation in how English is actually spoken and you will frequently hear "also" at the end of (usually short) sentences or questions.  However, as your lesson suggests, if you want to speak in this proper way then put "also" before the verb:

> I also do.

Other examples:

> She will go to the store too
>
> She will go to the store as well
>
> She will also go to the store.