# How to tell when I should use "too" and when I should use "also"?

Tags: word-choice

There are some words that makes me confused (the grammar and speaking). One that makes me confused is when I need to use it "too" and when "also"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [He works in the shop and she does too / also / as well](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/120856/he-works-in-the-shop-and-she-does-too-also-as-well)

Answer (score 1):

In many contexts it's an arbitrary stylistic choice whether to use ***too*** or ***also***.

Sometimes it's relevant that we *tend* to use ***also*** adverbially *before* a verb (the specific verb following isn't the *only* thing being done). Conversely, we tend to use ***too*** adjectivally *after* some noun (where that noun is often the syntactic *subject* of an utterance). Consider...

> 1: *I **too** want X*
> (someone else wants X, *and so do I*)
> 2: *I **also** want X*
> (I want X, *and I want something else*)

Note that #1 only ever has the stated meaning, but #2 is quite capable of being used with *either* meaning. ***Also<sup>1</sup>*** (not normally ***Too*** here), #2 would often, but not always, carry heavy stress if it was intended to carry the first meaning (so if there's no such additional stress, it probably carries the second meaning).

To further complicate things, there's...

> 3: *I want X **too***
> (common construction)
> 4: *I want X **also***
> (relatively uncommon construction)

...where imho *both* versions are equally capable of carrying both meanings, and only the exact context will tell you which applies.

---

<sup>1</sup> There will probably be some contexts where only *one* of the words (and/or one possible position) is acceptable. But although I've called attention to my own decision to use ***Also*** as flagged up above, I think only misguided pedants would characterise ***Too*** as "incorrect" there. It's just a much less common choice.